# ¿Cómo de seguro es este sistema de login?

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, login

Estoy haciendo una app a la que van a acceder varias personas y necesito un sistema de login en condiciones ya que en principio la idea es que sea público aunque controlado ya que no se va a poder registrar cualquiera, los registros se realizan manualmente por la administración de la app. Me gustaría consultar como de seguro es y en que se puede mejorar.

**login.php**

```
  session_start(); if(isset($_SESSION['id']) OR isset($_COOKIE['id'])) header('Location: /app');
  include '../../db.php'; $mensaje = 0;

  if(isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['pass'])) {
    $user = $_POST['user']; $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $sql_user = "SELECT * from users WHERE users_user LIKE '%{$user}%'";
    $consulta_user = mysqli_query($con, $sql_user);
    $filas_user = mysqli_num_rows($consulta_user);

    if($filas_user !== 0) {
      $mostrar_user = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta_user);
      $passHash = $mostrar_user['users_pass'];

      if(password_verify($pass, $passHash)) {
        $id = $mostrar_user['users_id'];
        $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
        $_SESSION['user'] = $mostrar_user['users_user'];
        $_SESSION['nombre'] = $mostrar_user['users_nombre'];
        $_SESSION['email'] = $mostrar_user['users_email'];

        if($_POST['recordar'] == 1) {
          setcookie('id', $id, time() + 365 * 24 * 60 * 60);
          setcookie('user', $mostrar_user['users_user'], time() + 365 * 24 * 60 * 60);
          setcookie('nombre', $mostrar_user['users_nombre'], time() + 365 * 24 * 60 * 60);
          setcookie('email', $mostrar_user['users_email'], time() + 365 * 24 * 60 * 60);
        }
        
        $sql_control = "UPDATE users SET users_fechau = NOW() WHERE users_id = $id";
        mysqli_query($con, $sql_control);

        header('Location: /app');
      } else $mensaje = 1;
    } else $mensaje = 1;
  }
```

Cualquier aporte es bienvenido.

Comment: Esto se va a desplegar usando un certificado emitido por una CA pública? Cual es la arquitectura de despliegue de la aplicación que usa este login? Cómo se controla el acceso a la administración del servidor donde se instala esta aplicación? Todo esto y más, hace parte de "hacer segura la aplicación y restringir el acceso a las cosas que ve un usuario autenticado". Sobre la cookie, yo revisaría si queda httponly, si se crea _secure_ o no, qué algoritmo se está usando para hacer hash de la contraseña,... hacerle review al código sin un problema específico termina con opiniones, como puedes ver.

Comment: Además de lo mencionado por Alfabravo, le recomiendo que busque sobre el tema de Inyección SQL y cómo evitarlo en PHP, por cierto, la función  [mysqli_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) padece de ese problema (aunque en la doc en español no lo mencionan).

Comment: Vulnerable a inyección SQL en la consulta user, no debes usar la variable $user tal cual dentro de la query. Y espero que en la app no te valga con la cookie para estar logueado, porque entonces cualquiera puede acceder, usando una cookie creada a mano. Los datos de la sesión deben de estar sólo en el lado del servidor.

Comment: He eliminado las cookies ya que no me son necesarias y por ahora no se va usar. El hash de las contraseñas se crea con password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); (60 caracteres)

Answer (score 0):

**Primero**: Tienes un error de lógica  ya que  estas obteniendo el usuario con un `like`

Imagina lo siguiente: digamos que en el campo usuario yo solo escribo una letra `a` esto devolverá todos los usuarios que tengan una letra `a` en el campo `users_user`. entones como se con que usuario estoy accediendo?

**Segundo** : Digamos que solucionas el error quitando el `like` y poniendo en su lugar un `=`.   Ahora tienes el segundo problema. `inyecciones SQL`

Un ejemplo rapido de un inyeccion SQL: Digamos que tu código queda de la siguiente manera:

```html
$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$sql_user = "SELECT * from users WHERE users_user = '$user'";
```

Bastaría únicamente escribir en el `<input name="user">` lo siguiente `' or 1 = 1`
esto daría como resultado el primer usuario de tu tabla   la sentencia SQL quedaria de la siguiente manera.

```html
  // recuerda que el valor que escribio el usuario  es  ' or 1 = 1
  $user = $_POST['user'];
  $pass = $_POST['pass'];
  //esta seria tu sentencia original
  $sql_user = "SELECT * from users WHERE users_user = '$user'";
  
  // esto seria lo que llegaria a mySQL
  
  SELECT * from users WHERE users_user = '' or 1 = 1
```

Este es un ejemplo muy muy  básico. pero las inyecciones SQL pueden ser FATALES para tu sistema.

Como recomendaciones:

- Utiliza `Sentencias Preparadas`
- Utiliza correos electrónicos como nombres de usuario así podrás verificar que realmente se una persona la que esta intentando logear.
- Sanitizacion de datos (remueve caracteres ilegales como ' " )

Comment: Buenas, he reemplazado el LIKE por =, además he hecho el test de la inyección SQL y me lanza el siguiente error: Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_num_rows(): Argument #1 ($result) must be of type mysqli_result,  mysqli_num_rows(false) #1 {main}. Sucede siempre que añado a un campo las comillas simples o las dobles (' ó ").

Comment: Escapa el valor entonces  `$sql_user = "SELECT * from users WHERE users_user = \"$user\"";`